# Laravel Broadcasting auth route[login] not defined

Tags: laravel, angular, passport, pusher, broadcast

Hola estoy tratando de crear un canal privado con pusher mi API en laravel pero como autenticacion uso passport, el asunto esta que en el archivo BroadcastServiceProvider añado esta linea

`Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);`

pero me da un error

Route [login] not defined.

http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth

pero si dejo solo

`Broadcast::routes();` me notifica un 403 forbiden

no se si hay algo que me falta o que puede ser ya he descomentado la linea
en app.php

`App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class`

Answer (score 0):

Intentaré responder, aunque creo hace falta más código. Estoy trabajando con Laravel actualmente, por lo cual tuve que verlo en algún momento.

Según entiendo tú problema está en el archivo BroadcastServiceProvider.php es necesario que comentes la línea:

App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class

Es preferible no moverla. En mi caso yo lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
Broadcast::routes();

require base_path('routes/channels.php');
```

Sin olvidar que hay que añadir las importaciones, en este caso la siguiente:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Y en el archivo channels.php tengo:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;});
```

Aclaro esto es en mi caso, debido a que no se como es tú código no puedo dar más información al respecto. Espero te sirva de algo.